# XDrawString not working on Solaris

Tags: c++, solaris, xlib

I am using `XDrawString` on Solaris 10 as well as SunOS 2.6. I am drawing everything to pixmap and then outputting the final pixmap. The method works on older version but on newer version it doesn't seem to work showing nothing as text.

Answer (score 1):

hhafez is probably right we need more info.  But across environments might have something to do with when and how you call XFlush() or XSynchronize() see the man pages for these here's one:
http://www.xfree86.org/current/XSynchronize.3.html.